# Immediate downvote

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I tried to answer a question on Stack Overflow since it was quite new and had no answers yet.
I typed it and as soon as I pressed Post and my answer has been displayed it was already downvoted; moreover there were two additional answers, one a couple of minutes "older" upvoted, and the other one few seconds "younger" compared to mine, already downvoted. How can it be possible?

Please excuse me if this is not the correct place to put this question.

Comment: Sometimes evaluating an answer can indeed be done in a split second. Especially for common problems where an experienced user just *knows* that some less experienced users will almost certainly trot out certain bad solutions (cough-PHP-utf8_encode-cough), such answers can be spotted immediately and are just as quickly downvoted. Depending on the timing this may all happen while your page is still reloading. Having said that, if the answer you're talking about is the answer I think it is, then that's pretty long and should at least take a few seconds to evaluate...

Comment: Having said that, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/476

Comment: If it helps, this is pretty commonplace.

Comment: @deceze I suppose you found my answer :). My only concern is only on the timings: I couldn't see it normal, and one posted few seconds later was already down voted, as they were never been normal

Comment: Well, depending on how fast your internet connection is and how the stars are aligned it may take 10~15 seconds for the page to reload and maybe a few more to scroll down to the right spot on the page. Perhaps the answer was at +-0 for some of that time, but then got downvoted right as you looked (it updates live). So there may have been a good 30 seconds for someone to read and vote on it?! Doesn't sound all that implausible.

Comment: Ok, seems to me I have to blame the stars :) In any case it took only two or three seconds to be displayed ....

Comment: @Simone You don't need to blame the stars.  Someone (possibly two someones, we can't know) went out of their way to explicitly inform you of problems with your answer that should be improved.  You could blame luck/coincidence that someone managed to find the problem with your answer so quickly, but to just assume that there is no merit to the vote would be willfully disregarding the valuable feedback you've been given.

Comment: @Servy I recognize my solution was not valid, and I'm not blaming for the down votes i could deserve ... it is only strange to me the way it has happened. I'm not wining for being down voted, I was only curious to understand ...

Comment: Sadly, with many questions, it would be better if they were downvoted and closed before they were asked.

Answer (score 10):

The use of websockets means that anyone viewing the page is *immediately* notified of new answers.  You already have a comment on your answer explaining what's wrong it, so you have a pretty plausible explanation for why it was downvoted.

Comment: My problem is not why, but how: the problem is that my answer directly appeared to me down voted, without showing "normal"; for what concern the comment, the first one appeared only 10~15 minutes later and i don't think it has been put by the same one down voted (that in any case i deserved)

Comment: @Simone That's true, but it does give you a *plausible* explanation for why another user may have had a problem with it.  It could have been another user, and it could have been for a different reason, but it's still something that you know is a problem that you can improve.

Comment: @Simone Some people make it a point to not comment right after they downvote so that they don't appear to be the downvoter. Perhaps you are a reasonable person who can handle fair criticism without flying off the handle but there are some who *will* seek revenge no matter how objectively faulty their answer was.